# yarn encore app.js file not found on live server

Tags: symfony, webpack, yarnpkg, webpack-encore

My app.js works fine locally, but I get a 404 not found when running on the live website.  The file is compiled in the /web/js folder.

```
    {% block javascripts %}
     <script src="{{ asset('js/runtime.js')}}"></script>
     <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
```

note framework is symfony 2.8

webpack.config.js looks this, not sure if the setPublic path should be as below or somewhere else..

```
  var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

  Encore
 // directory where compiled assets will be stored
 .setOutputPath('web/js/')
 // public path used by the web server to access the output path
 .setPublicPath('/js')


/*
 * ENTRY CONFIG
 *
 * Add 1 entry for each "page" of your app
 * (including one that's included on every page - e.g. "app")
 *
 * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
 * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if you JavaScript imports CSS.
 */
 .addEntry('app', './app/Resources/assets/js/app.js')

.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

.autoProvidejQuery()

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

Is runtime.js required and it seems to be needed locally but uncertain of use

Comment: What is look like your webpack.config.js?

Comment: @Zamir10 thanks I've ammended my question with the webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0):

Just put your asset files to web folder. asic webpack.config.js should look like this:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js');
```

Then to build the assets, run this command:

```
yarn encore dev
```

After successfully compiling you can use your complied assets in twig template.

```
<script src="{{ asset('build/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: He is using Symfony 2.8, so public dir should be `web` instead of `public`.